# Type 'System.Data.DataRow' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, clone, deep-copy

I am getting following error while serializing the object into steams.

> Type 'System.Data.DataRow' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable

```
internal static object CloneObject(object obj)
{
    MemoryStream ms = null;
    object objClone = null;

    try
    {
        // Create a memory stream and a formatter.
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bf= new BinaryFormatter();

        // Serialize the object into the stream.
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        // Position stream pointer back to first byte.
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // De serialize into another object.
        objClone = bf.Deserialize(ms);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release memory.
        if (ms != null)
            ms.Close();
    }
    return objClone;
}
```

By reading the exception, it looks like there is a `dataRow` in the object which is not serialized.

How can I identify the `dataRow` which is causing this problem in my code?

Comment: `System.Data.DataRow` is not marked as [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx), as can be seen from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,2b12751a7855832d).  Your  cloning technique only works for types so marked.  To deep-copy a data table, use [`DataTable.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For a data set, [`DataSet.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: People here directly downvote the question, than understanding the problem..

Comment: Microsoft forum is much better than this..

Comment: I didn't downvote; stackoverflow might have been able to give more help if you had included an example class that caused the exception when cloned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause of this... In one of the class file there is a global dataRow variable declared. And class is marked as serialized.

After removing that dataRow, issue has been resolved.

Thanks,

-Siva

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to find where this code is being called from.

In Visual Studio, you can right click on the function name and click "Find All References" - which should give you a start (see [documentation on finding objects, definitions and references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sadchd3(v=vs.100).aspx))

The other option is to use the [CallStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) when you are debugging to find out where the call is coming from.

If you are trying to clone a `DataTable` the [`DataTable.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) method is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to serialize an instance of a class, the class has to be marked as **[Serializable]**. DataRow isn't marked so you can't serialize objects of type DataRow.

Comment: What about `ISerializable`? That doesn't need you class marked with an attribute...

Comment: Could be used too, although that's for specialized serialization.